# Set MinDate on date control to restrict selection, but need the value to remain once it's selected

Tags: c#, datepicker

I have a form where I have a datetime editor. I don't want a user to be able to pick a date before today on the datetime editor, so I set the MinDate to be Date.Now.Date. Once a date is selected the datetime picker is disabled.

The problem I'm running into is that once the date chosen has passed, the datetime editor is still enforcing the MinDate and it defaults the date to "today".

*Example*

1. On 1/1/2014 a user sets the date on the control to 1/22/2014 (the
   date control becomes disabled, preventing users from making changes to
   it ever again).
2. The date shows fine after that.
3. Fast forward to today (1/23/2014), the date control now shows
   1/23/2014 because showing 1/22/2014 would violate the date control's
   MinDate setting of "today".

Since the date field will never be editable again, I considered the workaround of removing the MinDate once a date has been chosen, but this doesn't seem like the best solution.

TL;DR Set MinDate on date control to enforce business logic, but date control with MinDate won't allow date to continue showing as historical information once the MinDate is past the date chosen.

Is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: have you tried setting the mindate `SelectedDate` as well as `DbSelectedDate` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant set the the datetime control as less than the min value.